# SaxPrase Exception in Android

Tags: android, xml-parsing

Am using SaxParsing in android. It works fine but on continuously parsing every time it throwing SaxPraseException.( that means if am parsing and going back to previous screen)

Am using Asynctask, in which am retrieving data.

Comment: Please add more information and stacktrace

Comment: Can you post some code where the error is occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am using static method and retrieving...this is the main cause of that exception.

I removed static ones.

now its working..

source: [Memory leaks android](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)